# network analyzer - handling captured pcap files

Tags: networking, pcap, libpcap, packet-capture, winpcap

I'm about to write a program that analyzes network traffic. 
after searching for answers and not finding any on the net, a few questions:

1. Capturing network traffic - I'm using the winpcap library for the analyzis. 
   does the capture functionality captures all packets or loss of packets can occur.
   and if loss occurs how do I prevent it from happening.
2. Analyzing network traffic - is it better to capture (and analyze) each packet separately or to capture some (in each time) as chunks.
3. What's easier to handle - tcpdump or winpcap library functionality
   (I am using the winpcap library at the current time)
4. Example code to capture and analyze pcap file - not those from jnetpcap website.

jnetpcap website offers examples but not dealing with this questions.

Thanks in advance,
Andrei

Answer (score 0):

For the first two points: I do not know if there are some packets lost while capturing via Winpcap but I think capturing packets **in chunks is better** (i.e. in one pcap file) than to save each packet in different files because saving them in different files will have overhead of creating different files every time.

For the 3rd point: I haven't used Winpcap but I didn't see a problem while using Jnetpcap library.

And for the last: For wincap, you can see the examples here http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcapsamps.html and step by step guide http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcap__tut.html

Comment: I don't think OP is talking about saving packets to different files in 2.